# PowerShell Elevate Session State on XM Cloud

Tags: powershell-extensions, xm-cloud

How can I perform an Elevate Session State in `Sitecore PowerShell ISE` on `XM Cloud` running in local container?

On the Elevate Session State, I need to "**Enter your credentials to validate access to Execute a script**." it tries to use my xmcloud username but it gives an error message

```
Could not validate access using the provided credentials.
```

Or else how can I execute and create PowerShell scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a Solution to be able to run Sitecore PowerShell Script, e.t.c. Is change the **elevationAction** in the config to Allow or Confirm, then you don't need to enter a password.

Set the elevationAction can be done by setting the environment var **SITECORE_SPE_ELEVATION** in your docker-compose.yml
the patch file \Include\v.Spe\s.Spe.config is using this environment var, $(env:SITECORE_SPE_ELEVATION)

Or patch it your self but be sure it is after the s.Spe.config, place in a zz_spe folder for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore role:require="XMCloud">
    <powershell>
      <userAccountControl>
        <tokens><token name="Default"  elevationAction="Block"/>
              <token name="Console" expiration="00:05:00" elevationAction="Allow" patch:instead="*[@name='Console']"/>
              <token name="ISE" expiration="00:05:00" elevationAction="Allow" patch:instead="*[@name='ISE']"/>
              <token name="ItemSave" expiration="00:05:00" elevationAction="Allow" patch:instead="*[@name='ItemSave']"/>
            </tokens>
      </userAccountControl>
    </powershell>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this for local instances is:

1. Add `SITECORE_SPE_ELEVATION: "Allow"` to your `docker-compose.override.yml` file:

```yml
services: 
  cm:
    environment:
      SITECORE_SPE_ELEVATION: "Allow"
```

2. Run `./down.ps1` in your terminal
3. Run `./up.ps1` in your terminal

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to modify the environment variable SITECORE_SPE_ELEVATION and set it to Block, Confirm, or Allow according to this documentation:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/environment-variables.html